# PHP Insert query retuning success but not inserting data to the table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having issues with insert queries on a database that I am porting my code over to. I have first of all had to change everything from mysqli to PDO which fixed every problem except for this one.

I have tried using prepared statements, I have tried hardcoding the entry values. I have also verified that permissions are not the issue, plus that would return a fail I assume?

This query always returns success on all entries but does not enter anything into the database, however I have an update query written in the same script if I find a row already there so I know the variables are being populated.

I am at a loss for what could be causing the issue

here is the code:

```
$currKey = 1;

             foreach ($answer as $a)
            {
                $insertquery = "INSERT INTO table(userid, step_number, question_number, answer) VALUES ($userid, $stepNumber, $currKey, '$a')";

                if (!$stmt = $db->query($insertquery))
                {
                    $response = array();
                    $response["success"] = 0;
                    $response["message"] = "Error at insert query";
                }
                else
                {
                    $response = array();
                    $response["success"] = 1;
                    $resppnse["message"] = "success";

                    $currKey += 1;
                }
            }


            echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: change this                `$insertquery = "INSERT INTO table(userid, step_number, question_number, answer) VALUES ($userid, $stepNumber, $currKey, '$a')";`
 to this 
                `$insertquery = "INSERT INTO table(userid, step_number, question_number, answer) VALUES ($userid, $stepNumber, $currKey, $a)";`

Comment: this did not work

Comment: what is $stmt ? I hope it is not the prepared statemet because you need the connection to execute the query: `$conn->query($sql)`

Comment: rectified this issue, but still no data being inerted

Comment: Did you rectify both of them and test ?

Comment: yes $db is my PDO connection string, and $stmt is the object I pass the query result into, that way i can check for errors/successes

Comment: Okay to insert you need exec function `$db->exec($sql)`

Comment: does that require the execute permission?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137543/discussion-between-sadok-mtir-and-geolaw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multi-pronged issue and one people will probably never have themselves, but hopefully this will give people some things to consider and motions to go through when working with this kind of situation.

So the first major issue is that my text editor decided to go on strike. Meaning no matter what I did in an attempt to debug, nothing was happening.

Next, once I had moved over to another machine to continue my work. I had managed to discern that `$rows = $stmt->fetchAll()` will always be > 0 but returns a bool, unlike `$stmt->get_result->fetch_assoc()` from `mysqli` which returns an array and therefore I can get a count. I figured this out by realizing that my insert query was never being hit (please use good and descriptive debug messages).

After that I changed `"INSERT INTO table(userid, step_number, question_number, answer) VALUES ($userid, $stepNumber, $currKey, '$a')";`
to `"INSERT INTO table(userid, step_number, question_number, answer) VALUES ('$userid', '$stepNumber', '$currKey', '$a')";` and there we have it.

Thanks to all that helped, this has been a frustrating 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

So to execute a select query you need the `query()` function:  [PDO::query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

And In order to perform CUD operations you need to pass by `exec()` function:
[PDO::exec](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)

So here try to change `if (!$stmt = $db->query($insertquery))` to `if(!$results= $db->exec($insertquery))`

Comment: this didn't work, however I have realised now that it is returning success regardless of what happens, I reversed the if statement and it returned the same outcome

Comment: look: **PDO::exec() returns the number of rows that were modified or deleted by the SQL statement you issued. If no rows were affected, PDO::exec() returns 0**.

Comment: @geolaw So if you got 0 and you have the inverse ! then the first statement will be executed ==> what means that an error happen and data were not saved. I do not know what problem you still have now , what is the return value after the execute?

Comment: It appears that my editor has stopped saving changes to the file despite it saying it has, I'm currently seeing if that is what my issue is

Comment: Okay. Then try to make the changes and let me know if the issue was solved.