# AJAX can't put in all values from form. Insert QUERY

Tags: php, html, ajax

What's wrong in my codes? I dont think that the back end is the issue here, I cant find the logic error here. It says successful but does not insert the values from form. I'm newbie in using ajax. Please understand.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="AddProduct" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
 labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
           <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add 
Products</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <form>
        <div class="modal-body">
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  
 name="product_name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
              <small id="namenotif" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product Description</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" 
 id="product_description"  name="description" aria- 
 describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
              <small id="namenotif" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product Price</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price"  
 name="product_price" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter 
email">
              <small id="namenotif" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product Discount</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="discount"  
name="product_discount" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter 
email">
              <small id="namenotif" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product Image</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="image"  
name="product_image" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
              <small id="namenotif" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product Quantity</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity"  
name="product_quantity" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter 
email">
              <small id="namenotif" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleSelect1">Select Product Cat</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="category" name 
 ="product_category">
                <option value="Regular">Regular</option>
                <option value="Sale">Sales</option>
                <option value="FeaturedProduct">Featured Products</option>

              </select>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveproduct" 
name="save">Save Product</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click","#saveproduct",function(){
   var name = $("#_name").val();
   var description = $("#description").val();
   var price = $("#price").val();
   var discount = $("#discount").val();
   var image = $("#image").val();
   var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
   var category = $("#category").val();
   $.ajax({
    url:"addproduct.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{
          name:name,
          description:description,
          price:price,
          discount:discount,
          image:image,
          quantity:quantity,
          category:category
          }, 
    success:function(data){
    alert("Successful");
       }
     });
  });
});
</script>



require_once('conn.php');
if(!empty($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$discount = $_POST['discount'];
$image = $_POST['image'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$query ="INSERT into products(
                         name,
                         description,
                         price,
                         discount,
                         image,
                         quantity,
                         category
                         )values(
                         '$name',
                         '$description',
                         '$price',
                         '$discount',
                         '$image',
                         '$quantity',
                         '$category'
                          )";
$sql = mysqli_query($con,$query);
}
```

This code above is php code for my insert query, if you can notice, I just put product image in a variable because Im only testing how to insert using ajax.

Comment: Try printing data in (alert(data)) instead of successfull see what you get

Comment: @JaiDixit  Thats a good idea, its says "Locahost says :(Blank)

Comment: I hope this Thread will help you See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668522/php-insert-query-retuning-success-but-not-inserting-data-to-the-table

Comment: You will want to confirm that PHP is receiving all the POST data. Once it's collected, then you want to return some amount of data when the content is successfully added to the database. This is why your AJAX gets no response data. Maybe return the new ID number or "Successful" or `true` or `false` upon success or error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider the following in your PHP:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products(
  product_name,
  product_description,
  product_price,
  product_discount,
  product_image,
  product_quantity,
  product_category
) values (
  '$product_name',
  '$product_description',
  '$product_price',
  '$product_discount',
  '$product_image',
  '$product_quantity',
  '$product_category'
)";

if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}

mysqli_close($connection);
```

This will send data back to your AJAX Script. You could then do:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"addproduct.php",
  type:"POST",
  data: {
    product_name: product_name,
    product_description: product_description,
    product_price: product_price,
    product_discount: product_discount,
    product_image: product_image,
    product_quantity: product_quantity,
    product_category: product_category
  }, 
  success:function(data){
    console.log("AJAX Success:", data);
  }
});
```

This way you can see that PHP was able to connect and update the database or if it encountered an error you have access to that Error data.

In regards to your SQL Code, it can also be exploited, please review: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: testing connection and condition under insert query brought me to see the error. It says the column from db didnt match the variable I included in code. Thank you for that. @Twisty

Comment: @Jaz the code is susceptible to SQL Injection. You have nothing to filter the input. See: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @Twisty  how can I avoid it anyway?

Comment: @Jaz consider using MySQLi Prepared statements. The article I linked discusses options.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thank you for that Ill practice it later

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner do you have social media account?

Answer (score -1):

first check the PHP mysql connection is connected successfully. try to use error handling statements "TRY/CATCH"

see here http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php for debugging code with try/catch blocks

Comment: I echo "Connected"  in trying to confirm if my mysql connection is connected successfully. Thats the way I checked it.